# KDB: Function optimization

Tags: kdb

I have 2 table in kdb as below

```
q)table1:([]A:1 2 3 5 5 6 2 1;B:`HAK`ZAK`NAK`AAK`AZK`HAK`ZAK`HAK;C:2000.01.01+0 1 2 3 4 0 1 0)
q)table1
A B   C
----------------
1 HAK 2000.01.01
2 ZAK 2000.01.02
3 NAK 2000.01.03
5 AAK 2000.01.04
5 AZK 2000.01.05
6 HAK 2000.01.01
2 ZAK 2000.01.02
1 HAK 2000.01.01
q)table2:([]B:`HAK`ZAK`NAK`AAK`AZK;Z:`NAFK`RFK`NAFK`RFK`ORQ)
q)table2
B   Z
--------
HAK NAFK
ZAK RFK
NAK NAFK
AAK RFK
AZK ORQ
```

I want to modify Table1 column B as per mapping of Table 2.
eg wherever in table1 columnB has word "HAK", then look in table2 columnB and replace table1 with respective table2 columnz
Same for all rows for table1.

final output i want is table1 should be updated like below.

```
A B    C
-----------------
1 NAFK 2000.01.01
2 RFK  2000.01.02
3 NAFK 2000.01.03
5 RFK  2000.01.04
5 ORQ  2000.01.05
6 NAFK 2000.01.01
2 RFK  2000.01.02
1 NAFK 2000.01.01
```

The function which I came up with is below.

```
hfun:
{$[
x in `$("HAK");`$("NAFK");
x in `$("ZAK");`$("RFK");
x in `$("NAK");`$("NAFK");
x in `$("AAK");`$("RFK");
x in `$(AZK);`$("ORQ");
x]}


finalOutput:update B:hfun'[B] from table1
```

The above function is working as expected but its not feasible to write every time a new function for new mappings or if table2 has 200 rows.

Can someone please take a look and advise further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary update instead of the loop w/ condition:

```
dict:`HAK`ZAK`NAK`AAK`AZK!`NAFK`RFK`NAFK`RFK`ORQ;
update B^dict B from table1

(with spaces)
table1:([]A:1 2 3 5 5 6 2 1;B:(`$"HAK z";`$"ZAK";`$"NAK";`$"AAK";`$"AZK";`$"HAK";`$"ZAK";`$"HAK");C:2000.01.01+0 1 2 3 4 0 1 0)
table2:([]B:(`$"HAK z";`$"ZAK";`$"NAK";`$"AAK";`$"AZK");Z:`NAFK`RFK`NAFK`RFK`ORQ)

dict:exec B!Z from table2;
update B^dict B from table1
```

Comment: thanks connor, what if table1 columnB has space in between words. eg   `HAK 1  `HAK 2  `HAK 3    Is there way we can achive this? I have 80-200 records in table2. Also can we create a dictionary directly using table2?

Comment: @Haiderali Connor's second example of generating `dict` using the `exec` statement will work regardless of spaces etc.

Comment: Nice wan Connor

Comment: Awesome It worked, thanks a lot Connor, really appriciate your quick respose.

Answer (score 4):

Could also use an [amend](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/amend/) to achieve this:

```
@[table1;`B;(!/)table2`B`Z]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
update B:({x[;0]!x[;1]}flip value flip table2)'[B]from table1
```

This will achieve the desired outcome without the need to define extra variables or conditional statements also.
It also works with spaces in symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an lj

```
q)select A,B:B^Z,C from table1 lj `B xkey table2
A B    C
-----------------
1 NAFK 2000.01.01
2 RFK  2000.01.02
3 NAFK 2000.01.03
5 RFK  2000.01.04
5 ORQ  2000.01.05
6 NAFK 2000.01.01
2 RFK  2000.01.02
1 NAFK 2000.01.01
```